# Arrow on a href

Tags: css

What is causing to put arrow at the end of my menu

[image]

My CSS is really simple. Unless I use any a href tag I wont get any arrow, but if I use a href tag then the arrow will appear to the right.

```
div.horizontal
{
width:100%;
height:32px;
padding:0px 5px;
}
div.horizontal ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.horizontal li
{
float:left;
}
div.horizontal a
{
display:block;
width:96px;
}
div.horizontal a:link,div.horizontal a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#77b482;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
div.horizontal a:hover,div.horizontal a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1"><!-- CSS : blueprint Framework -->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
  <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]--><!-- Import fancy-type plugin for the sample page. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins/fancy-type/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><!-- Import buttons plugin // add nice button instead of input button -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins/buttons/screen.css"><!-- Import silk sprites plugin -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins/sprites/sprite.css">
   <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css3buttons.css">--><!-- Import link-icons plugin // add icons depending of type of link / file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins/link-icons/screen.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/override.css">
```

Comment: You are missing some CSS here.. there is nothing that defines your arrows. Can you show your HTML as well.

Comment: There has to be more code.

Comment: url of the actual page would help

Comment: Is this possibly an IE plug-in or "feature" that is the culprit? It looks familiar to an arrow I've seen while using IE before when mousing over links.

Comment: I was using css3button.css from the template generated by Shikiryu HTML5 Generator. But even if I comment out the line I am getting this arrow.

Comment: @Nepal12 Are you using IE? Have you tested this code across multiple browsers?

Comment: The HTML code in your question is not very helpful. We don't see your buttons and we can't see what is in the CSS files.

Comment: @TylerH : I am using all browser for testing and all of them are showing arrow. putvande : May be you can look at hotelhubbert . de

Comment: Please optimise those images! There's absolutely no reason why it needs to load a 4000px image. It slows down the homepage so much.

Comment: Also = `a[href^="http:"] { background-image: url("icons/external.png");}` - If you inspect the element with Firebug or Chrome developer tools, then you'll see the bit of CSS that is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this code from your CSS to remove those icons (EDIT: as Nick R mentioned as I was typing this).

```
a[href^="http:"] {
    background-image: url('icons/external.png');
```